# REQUEST_SCOPE bean with TARGET_CLASS proxy mode sees only null parameters when injected in other components, like @Service's or @Repository's

Tags: java, spring, scope, javabeans

I have a java bean defined as REQUEST_SCOPE and with TARGET_CLASS proxy mode. Something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class TestObjectConfiguration {
    @Bean("test-object")
    @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public UserInfo testObject() {
        TestObject object = new TestObject();

        object.setParameter("value");

        return object;
    }
}
```

The value is set on each request, taking some values from request headers, and that is the reason why I need test-object bean to be request scoped. For simplicity, in this example I just assign a "value" String.

Then I want to retrieve it from an `@Service` or `@Repository` (aka Singleton beans). I do it like this:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("test-object")
    private TestObject object;

    @Override
    public void myMethod () {
        logger.info(object.getParameter());
    }
}
```

(Assume a logger is defined in the service)

The value of `object.parameter` is null. Inspecting the bean, it is instantiated and I see CGLIB parameters within it, but any elements inside are null.

The class is simple, just private `String`s and a `List<String>`, with the corresponding setters and getters. Something similar to this:

```
public class TestObject {
    private String parameter;

    public String getParameter() {
        return parameter;
    }
    public void setParameter(String parameter) {
        this.parameter = parameter;
    }
}
```

I have checked several documentation sources, and they state that this combination should work. In practice, I see the bean instantiated at random times during the request (classes with @Controller, that call singleton `@Service`, that call DB `@Repository`), but always with all parameters `null`.

What I need is to store somehow information gathered from the headers, and make it accessible to `@Service` and `@Repository` classes during the request.

Any ideas on what am I missing? Does the proxy mode require some configuration I am forgetting or not finding in documentation?

Comment: Let me guess your `UserInfo` or methods on your `UserInfo` are `final`. Or you are looking with a debugger and then you are looking at the proxy instead of the actual instance.

Comment: It seems you were absolutely right. It is my inspector while debugging that cannot access the data and shows it as null, but when I log it all is perfectly fine. Thanks for orienting me in the right direction!